# Wrong types of operation '*' in glsl?

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

I am making a 3d game with lwjgl in java, and im using GLSL as the shaders. After trying to run the code i get:

> Sun May 29 17:53:13 BST 2016 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true 
>   ERROR: 0:34: '*' : wrong operand types no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'float' and a right operand of type 'uniform 10-element array of 3-component vector of float' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
>  
>  
>  Could not compile shader!

The code for the terrain fragment shader:

```
#version 140 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector[10];
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in float visibility;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D backgroundTexture;
uniform sampler2D rTexture;
uniform sampler2D gTexture;
uniform sampler2D bTexture;
uniform sampler2D blendMap;


uniform vec3 lightColour[10];
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;
uniform vec3 skyColour;

void main(void){

    vec4 blendMapColour = texture(blendMap, pass_textureCoords);

    float backTextureAmount = 1 - (blendMapColour.r + blendMapColour.g + blendMapColour.b);
    vec2 tiledCoords = pass_textureCoords * 40.0;
    vec4 backgroundTextureColour = texture(backgroundTexture, tiledCoords) * backTextureAmount;
    vec4 rTextureColour = texture(rTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColour.r;
    vec4 gTextureColour = texture(gTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColour.g;
    vec4 bTextureColour = texture(bTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColour.b;

    vec4 totalColour = backgroundTextureColour + rTextureColour + gTextureColour + bTextureColour;

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);

    vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector[i]);
        float nDotl = dot(unitNormal,unitLightVector);
        float brightness = max(nDotl,0.0);
        vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
        vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection,unitNormal);
        float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection , unitVectorToCamera);
        specularFactor = max(specularFactor,0.0);
        float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor,shineDamper);
        totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + brightness * lightColour[i];
        totalSpecular = totalSpecular + dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour[i];
    }
    totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse,0.2);

    out_Color =  vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * textureColour + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
    out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), out_Color, visibility);
}
```

The code for terrain vertext shader:

```
#version 140 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector[10];
out vec3 toCameraVector;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition[10];

const float density = 0.0035;
const float gradient = 5.0;

void main(void){

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCam;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        toLightVector[i] = lightPosition[i] - worldPosition.xyz;
    }
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

    float distance = length(positionRelativeToCam.xyz);
    visibility = exp(-pow((distance*density), gradient));
    visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

The code for vertex shader:

```
#version 140 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector[10];
out vec3 toCameraVector;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition[10];

uniform float useFakeLighting;

uniform float numberOfRows;
uniform vec2 offset;

const float density = 0.0035;
const float gradient = 5.0;

void main(void){

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCam;
    pass_textureCoords = (textureCoords/numberOfRows) + offset;

    vec3 actualNormal = normal;
    if(useFakeLighting>0.5){
        actualNormal = vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    }

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(actualNormal,0.0)).xyz;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        toLightVector[i] = lightPosition[i] - worldPosition.xyz;
    }
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

    float distance = length(positionRelativeToCam.xyz);
    visibility = exp(-pow((distance*density), gradient));
    visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

The code for fragment shader:

```
#version 140 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector[10];
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in float visibility;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform vec3 lightColour[10];
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;
uniform vec3 skyColour;

void main(void){

vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);

vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector[i]);
    float nDotl = dot(unitNormal,unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDotl,0.0);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection,unitNormal);
    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection , unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor,0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor,shineDamper);
    totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + brightness * lightColour;
    totalSpecular = totalSpecular + dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour[i];
}
totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse,0.2);

vec4 textureColour = texture(modelTexture,pass_textureCoords);
if(textureColour.a<0.5){
    discard;
}

out_Color =  vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * textureColour + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), out_Color, visibility);
}
```

I have looked through it myself plenty of times but im not that experienced with glsl so there is probably a mistake that i havent noticed.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to scale a vector of RGB values by a float, which is apparently not supported

Comment: @Nasso i just did what you said but, it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 34 of your fragment shader:

```
totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + brightness * lightColour;
```

You forgot to specify the indice of the light colour:

```
totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + brightness * lightColour[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that:

 first off what @Nasso said which was that instead of

```
lightColour;
```

it should have been

```
lightColour[i];
```

then after that there was a second error, which was easy to fix:

 instead of

```
out_Color =  vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * textureColour + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
```

i had to put

```
out_Color =  vec4(totalDiffuse,1.0) * totalColour + vec4(totalSpecular,1.0);
```

Comment: Be careful when watching ThinMatrix' tutorials !